# Mongoose Populate, Do I have to keep schemas in the same file?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am trying to populate by using Mongoose. This is what it looks like so far:

schema.ts

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: String,
  name: String,
});
const UserModel = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema, "users");

const ShiftSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  startTime: String,
  endTime: String,
});

ShiftSchema.virtual("user", {
  ref: "User",
  localField: "userId",
  foreignField: "id",
  justOne: true,
});

const ShiftModel = mongoose.model("Shift", ShiftSchema, "shifts");

export default ShiftModel;
```

shift.ts

```
const shifts = await ShiftModel.find({}).populate("user");
```

So this code is working fine, it is working as expects and populating user data into shift data.

What I'm currently having trouble with is organizing this. I need to separate schemas into separate files however if I try to separate the userSchema and UserModel into a different file, populate doesn't work anymore. Any ideas on a workaround for this?

Also, by the way, I am using a custom ID and not the default ID supplied by MongoDB.

What I've tried:

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: String,
  name: String,
});
export const UserModel = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema, "users");
```

When I try to run my script, I get an error saying that Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".

Comment: you can put it in a separate file, export it and import it in the file where you use it

Comment: I have tried that. And regarding importing it, as I am not directly using it, my listing will throw an error as the import is not being used.

Comment: It sounds to me like an "order of operations" thing. Make sure that the users schema/model have been initialized before you try to create the virtual field on your ShiftModel. Aside - what is the third argument of your `.model()` calls? According to [Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model), that's value should be a boolean that indicated whether or not to use mongodb _id, so shouldn't you just pass `true` instead of the string `user` or `shifts`?